# Microsoft Teams - Microsoft Graph API to return JSON with meetingURL

Tags: php, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

At our company, we are trying to implement this script so we can call a page and get in return a JSON file with a teams meeting URL generated everytime we call it.

We allways get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\ODataErrors\ODataError in C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\microsoft\microsoft-graph\src\Generated\Models\ODataErrors\ODataError.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\microsoft\kiota-serialization-json\src\JsonParseNode.php(108): Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\ODataErrors\ODataError::createFromDiscriminatorValue(Object(Microsoft\Kiota\Serialization\Json\JsonParseNode)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\microsoft\kiota-http-guzzle\src\GuzzleRequestAdapter.php(666): Microsoft\Kiota\Serialization\Json\JsonParseNode->getObjectValue(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\microsoft\kiota-http-guzzle\src\GuzzleRequestAdapter.php(160): Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter->throwFailedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array, Object(OpenTelemetry\API\Trace\NonRecordingSpan)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\php-http\promise\src\FulfilledPromise.php(39): Microsoft\Kiota\Http\GuzzleRequestAdapter->Microsoft\Kiota\Http{closure}(Object(GuzzleH in C:\xampp\htdocs\teamsapi\vendor\microsoft\microsoft-graph\src\Generated\Models\ODataErrors\ODataError.php on line 36**

1. We created the App on Azure, as a "Entreprise App" (Tested just App Registrations also, didn't work also) -- Created with Admin account;
2. Added this permissions: Calendars.ReadWrite, Mail.ReadWrite, OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All, User.Read, User.ReadWrite.All, VirtualEvent.Read.All (Granted Admin Consent);
3. Added Single-page applications redirect url: http://localhost/teamspai/index.php
4. Tested as Multitenant and Singletenant - not working both options;
5. Added Access using Powershell: New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy.. to the AppId and then Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy .. -Global;

We just need to return a JSON with the URL for the meeting.

Our code:

```
<?php 
include_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Abstractions\ApiException;
use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\ClientCredentialContext;
use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\OnlineMeeting;


$scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'];
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 
$tokenRequestContext = new ClientCredentialContext(
    $tenantId,
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret
);

$graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext);
$requestBody = new OnlineMeeting(); 
$result = $graphServiceClient->me()->onlineMeetings()->post($requestBody)->wait();
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Hope someone can help us!

I tried:

- Add Permissions
- Single Tenant
- Multi Tenant
- Access Policy
- Downgrade MSGraph
- Created new App

**EDIT**

Changed to user "byUserId" and now the error is gone.
But now, I am getting an empty JSON, just: {}

Comment: When using clientSecret you need application permissions to be granted and you can't call $graphServiceClient->me(), because you are not signed as any user. You need to access specific user $graphServiceClient->users({id})

Comment: Thank you! 
I changed to use the user id instead of "me" , but now i am getting:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Users\UsersRequestBuilder::onlineMeetings()"

Line changed to:
$result = $graphServiceClient->users('my-user-id-is-here')->onlineMeetings()->post($requestBody)->wait();

Comment: Using this instead removed the "undefined method" error, but i get the oDataError Again:
$result = $graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId('my-user-id-is-here')->onlineMeetings()->post($requestBody)->wait();

Comment: To fix the "undefined method" error, you need to use the correct method to retrieve the
`UsersRequestBuilder` object. `$result = $graphServiceClient->users('my-user-id-is-here')->onlineMeetings()->post($requestBody)->execute();`

Comment: If you are still getting the ODataError after making the above changes, it could be due to incorrect permissions or an issue with the authentication process. Make sure that the Azure app registration has the necessary permissions (OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All) and that the authentication process is correctly configured.